# Can't understand method - Java

Tags: java, methods

I have the following method:

```
private boolean checkVictory (char player)
    {
        boolean victory = false;    // by default no victory

        for (int i = 0; i < _board[0].length; i++)
        {
            Cell c = new Cell(i, getLastOccupiedCells()[i].getRow());
            if (maxSequence(player, c) == 4)
                victory = true;
        }
        return victory;
    }
```

This method is a part of a 'four in a row' game.
maxSequence(player, c) should return the longest sequence who contains the cell 'c' and the sign 'player' (means 'X' or 'O').

Just wonder for the meaning of the #4 at line: `if (maxSequence(player, c) == 4)`

thnx !

Comment: As a side note that should better be `if (maxSequence(player, c) >= 4)` since in theory, you could get a sequence of 7 cells if you have 2 sequences of 3 and connect them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if` is a *keyword*, a word in the language with special meaning. The statement...

```
if (maxSequence(player, c) == 4)
    victory = true;
```

...means:

"if the result returned from `maxSequence` (with argument `player` and `c`) returns 4, then execute a statement setting `victory` to true."

Here's a good link:

- [The Java tutorials: The if-then and if-then-else Statements](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html)

Comment: well, you can't name it `final` since that's a keyword too, but you could name it `goal` or something for instance. I would actually create a member field (class variable) like this: `private final static int GOAL = 4;`

Comment: how about: "final int WIN_SEQ = 4;" inside the method ? the method itself defined as 'private' so I will not have to worry for it.

Comment: Sure, that's fine. Usually you put constants like these on class-level though. But there's nothing wrong with putting it inside the method.

Comment: Why on Class level ? how about encapsulation for each method itself ? after all, the Class of this method is a public one.

Comment: You could still make the field private. Since it will have the same value for all objects of the class, it makes sense to let it be static, and you can't have static local variables in Java. But as I said, it is perfectly fine to have it as a local variable as well.

Comment: You normally put those constants on class level since you often want to access them in multiple methods. You might also want to read it elsewhere, e.g. in order to display it.

Answer (score 1):

If 4 items of the same type (the one found in cell c) are lined in a row (in a sequence) then one of the players has won